# how to enable files api in salesforce integration project?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I am trying to integrate saleforce with my project. While accessing the url 
"/chatter/feeds/files/me" i am getting the error "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG:files API is not enabled for this Organization or user"..

```
RestResponse getResponse=restClient.sendSync(RestMethod.GET, "/services/data/v23.0/chatter/feeds/files/me, null); 
System.out.prinln(getResponse.toString()); // here i am getting the response as "API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG:files API is not enabled for this Organization or user".. "
```

Please help.........

Comment: Are you sure your salesforce edition includes API access ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the restclient URL try using v24.0,which is the latest salesforce API version.

Comment: thank you for ur suggestion. But using 24.0 i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this and got the same problem.
You may be having authorization problems. Try checking your auth tockens once again